# Input required only if specific option is selected

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a form that contains a `select` and an `input` field. To simplify the example, let's say the three options of the `select` are `1`, `2`, and `3`.

I need to create a set of validation rules where `input` is only `required` if option `2` is selected. How can I create this rule?

Here is my set of rules so far:

```
$rules = array(
    'selectField' => 'required',
    'inputField' => '', // only required if option 2 is selected
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `required_if` validation rule?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-required-if

```
$rules = [
    'selectField' => 'required',
    'inputField' => 'required_if:selectField,2',
];
```